# Looking for a functionality in QGIS to find all neigbours in a polygon layer

Tags: qgis

I am looking for a functionality in QGIS to find all neigbours for each polygon in a polygon layer. The result should be a table with 2 ID-Columns: one for the polygon and the second for the neighbours.

I tried "spatial query" in QGIS with the layer as source and its copy as reference, but to no avail.

In Mapbasic of Mapinfo it would be a simple expression:

```
select t1.id1, t2.id2 from t1, t2 where t1.obj intersects t2.obj
```

(where t1 and t2 are two copies of the polygon layer).

Comment: What type of topology?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use vector tools (Vector -> Geometry tools -> Polygon centroids) to create a centroid layer of the polygons with IDs the same as the polygons
2. Convert that layer into PostGIS (if possible)
3. Use [Regina's](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic) or [Mackerron's](http://blog.mackerron.com/2011/03/10/postgis-nearest-neighbour/) implementations of nearest neighbour. You might have to do some sql modifications to be able to output an OD matrix.

*Note: I will try and work on this and get an updated answer tomorrow with a lot more details and an example*

Comment: Spatialite would be a nice quick solution rather then using PostGIS

Comment: @NathanW good point. I've never used spatialite. Feel free to edit or repost an answer using it and i'll delete my answer after that.

Comment: How about this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/qgis-polygon-layer-table-of-adjacent-polygons

Answer (score 2):

thanks a lot for your advice.

Meanwhile I came up with another solution:
1) create a tiny buffer for each object in one layer;
2) use Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect it with another copy - and here you are.

Not that simple as in MapInfo and a bit unreliable (there is a small probability that a buffer will touch a polygon, which is not a neighbour, but which is separated from the source one by a vary tiny strip that is smaller than the buffer).